# Can TypeScript recognise the effect that Array.filter might have on the type of the array?

Tags: typescript

Say I have the following array:

```js
type NullableArrayElement = {
  val: string | null;
};

const arr: NullableArrayElement[] = [{ val: 'a' }, { val: null }];
```

I want to filter out all the elements where `val` is null, so I've made a type guard to use with `filter`:

```js
function isNotNull<T>(x: T | null): x is T { return x !== null; }

const nonNullArray = arr.filter(x => isNotNull<string>(x.val));
```

Although none of the elements of `nonNullArray` have the property `val` set to `null`, TypeScript still thinks that the type of `nonNullArray` is `NullableArrayElement[]`. Is there any way to tell TypeScript that the type of `nonNullArray` is now `{ val: string }[]`?

I know the desired result can be achieved with `reduce`, but I like `filter` as it's shorter and clearer.

Comment: Only if you type the _actual callback_ appropriately, `(x): x is { val: string } => ...` (the inferred return type is simply `boolean`).

Comment: Yes, that'll do it! Thanks